# Manipulate incoming call

Tags: android, ios, react-native, flutter

I am trying to build Android/IOS application application with React Native and trying to gather knowledge about its ability in manipulating incoming calls, so for example user is getting incoming call from somebody, is it possible for React Native to just hide this screen? [image]

i've tried to gather all the modules and librarys for React Native which could perform such task but I could not find anything. so is this even possible, even in Flutter?

Comment: I don't think that is possible. Obviously not on iOS. All incoming calls are handled by the OS per se. So they don't let third party softwares to interrupt.

Comment: what about Android?

Comment: I'm not sure you can bypass the incoming call screen on Android either but I'm quite  not sure.

Comment: I am not saying to bypass I mean to manipulate, like resize it so it does not cover whole screen or so